# Event Dispatch is not working

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-events

I am updating a value for a record using lightning-record-edit-form update in the child component. After updating the record, I want to pass the updated record to the parent. It is not get passed when firing the custom event.

Child LWC HTML:

```
<lightning-record-edit-form record-id={accRecord.Id} object-api-name="Account" onsuccess={handleSuccess}>
```

Child LWC JS

```
handleSuccess(){
    console.log('IN SUCCESS'+this.accRecord);
    const event = new CustomEvent('child', {
        // detail contains only primitives
        detail: {key1:accRecord,key2:"Driller"}
        });
        this.dispatchEvent(event);
}
```

Parent HTML:

```
<c-account-details onchild={haldleChild}></c-account-details>
```

Parent JS:

```
 haldleChild(event){
    console.log('=======in Parent from child=='); 
    this.salesfrocedriller=event.detail.key1 +' '+event.detail.key2;
}
```

Please let me know the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
detail: {key1:accRecord,key2:"Driller"}
```

Should be:

```
detail: {key1:this.accRecord,key2:"Driller"}
```

To access class-level variables, you need to use `this`.

Note that the Id isn't automatically set, you may want to do that, as well:

```
handleSuccess(event){
    this.accRecord.id = event.detail.id
    const event = new CustomEvent('child', {
        // detail contains only primitives
        detail: {key1:this.accRecord,key2:"Driller"}
        });
        this.dispatchEvent(event);
}
```